# How to use macvim (mvim) in terminal after install with homebrew

Tags: macos, macvim

I installed macvim with homebrew and when i tip "mvim file" in terminal open the file in another window. Can I fix and open mvim in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The binary is needed by some plugins (YouCompleteMe), for one.

You can use the binary that is installed with macvim. By default, it's

```
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-144_3/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

You can simply alias vim to it in your shell config (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc.)

```
alias vim=/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-144_3/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

Answer (score 0):

MacVim (mvim) is not a terminal application.  If you want to open vim in a terminal, just use "vim" instead.

Answer (score 0):

We want the contents of the MacVim.app package to be in the PATH, but do this cleanly. So here's what I do:

```
cd /Applications; ln -s ../usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-151_1/MacVim.app
```

That gets you MacVim in /Applications, via a symlink that can be updated when the package is upgraded. Then add this to the PATH in the shell startup file:

```
PATH=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin:$PATH
```

Then when you upgrade you just change the symlink in /Applications and everything still works nicely.